# SwiftUI: Do I need to remove UIHostingController from the controller chain when I remove the controlled view from the view hierarchy?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swiftui, uicollectionview, uikit

I am trying to migrate UIKit Views in my app to SwiftUI. One of the central elements in my app is a UICollectionView. I am embedding the SwiftUI views using a UIHostingController - so far so good.

I am wondering, since my cells are reusable, what happens to the UIHostingController when the cell is recycled?
Do I need to take it out of the controller chain?
If I need to, what is the best way to do so? (storing the UIHostingController in the cell?)

Eg. a header view looks like this so far:

```
class HeaderViewCell: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    var layoutAttributes:GroupHeaderViewLayoutAttributes = GroupHeaderViewLayoutAttributes()
    
    public func attachContent(model:GroupHeaderModel, controller:UIViewController){
        let view = GroupHeaderView(model: model, layoutAttributes: self.layoutAttributes)
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        if let contentView = hostingController.view {
            controller.addChild(hostingController)
            self.addSubviewAndConstrains(contentView)
        }
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        layoutAttributes = GroupHeaderViewLayoutAttributes()
    }
    
    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        if let attributes = layoutAttributes as? TileViewLayout.HeaderViewAttributes {
            self.layoutAttributes.topBarHeight = attributes.topBarHeight
            self.layoutAttributes.indicatorWidth = attributes.indicatorWidth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find out anything about this? Wonder the same!

Comment: I have meanwhile removed the UICollectionView and refactored to pure SwiftUI